# Why I am getting Unresolved variable or type approvedPriceDealerCostForm in my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using angular 8 and I want to send approvedPriceDealerCostForm when I click my button but I get approvedPriceDealerCostForm Unresolved variable or type approvedPriceDealerCostForm error. Please see attached pic for more info. I want to keep my button in mat-dialog-actions.

```html
<ng-dave2-task-instance-progress
  [firstLayerClasses]="'invisible'"
>
  <ng-container *ngIf="(deal$ | async) as deal">
    <mat-dialog-content style="height: 85%" class="">
      <div class="flex flex-row p-2 bg-gray-200 items-start" style="min-height: 100%"
           *ngFor="let productBucket of productsWithBuckets; let j = index;let row"
      >              

        <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
          <form (ngSubmit)="onSend(approvedPriceDealerCostForm)" #approvedPriceDealerCostForm="ngForm">
            <div class="w-full flex flex-row">
              <mat-form-field class="w-1/2 pr-1">
                <input
                  matInput
                  placeholder="{{ 'totalsaleprice' | translate }}"
                  name="totalsaleprice"
                  [(ngModel)]="approvedPrice"
                  required
                />
                <mat-error>
                  {{ 'required' | translate }}
                </mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-form-field class="w-1/2 pr-1">
                <input
                  matInput
                  placeholder="{{ 'totaldealercost' | translate }}"
                  name="totaldealerCost"
                  [(ngModel)]="approvedDealerCost"
                  required
                />
                <mat-error>
                  {{ 'required' | translate }}
                </mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </form>


        </div>

      </div>
    </mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-dialog-actions align="end" class="mt-4 align-bottom align-text-bottom">
      <button (click)="onSend(approvedPriceDealerCostForm)" cdkFocusInitial class=""
              class="dave2-bg-success"
              mat-raised-button
              ngDave2Button
              color="primary"
              type="button"
              mat-button>
        {{ this.sending ? 'saving' : 'approveandsave' | translate }}
      </button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
  </ng-container>
</ng-dave2-task-instance-progress>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mat-dialog-actions` is outside of the `<form>` element and the local pointer `approvedPriceDealerCostForm` won't be resolved there.

What you could do though is to grab the reference to the form in your component ts file by using `@ViewChild` like this:

```
 @ViewChild('approvedPriceDealerCostForm') approvedPriceDealerCostForm: NgForm;
```

and then use `this.approvedPriceDealerCostForm` inside the `onSend` method or any other method you choose to use here.